# Regex to extract switches /switch=value

Tags: regex

I have a batch file that I need to extract switches from.
The switches are in this format.

```
/Switch1=Value1 /Switch2="Value 2" /Switch3 /Switch4="C:\Program Files\DIR"
```

I need Switch=Value or Switch (only if it doesn't have any value for e.g. Switch3) extracted.

I am a beginner to regex. So far I have tried `\/\w+=|\/\w+` this expression. But that doesn't give me a value.

Comment: What are the delimiters for the values ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You should probably use a parser/lexer for this kind of stuff. Quotes and backslashes and all that stuff make for a looong regex.

Comment: The only delimiter is quote character (for e.g. values for Switch2 and 4). Otherwise it will be a single value like Value1

Comment: @Rawing, can you please provide some reference to parser/lexter? I am using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want this,

```
\/\w+(?:=(?:(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1|\S+))?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cX2oW4/4)

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with escaped quotes, i.e. `/foo="\""`

Comment: or \/Switch\d+(?:=(?:(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1|\S+))? 
if doing explicit attribute name (gi flags)

Comment: I don't have a requirement for escaped quote, so this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not much information, but here is something in perl to get you going:

```
perl -p -i -e 'print "$1=$3\n" if /\/(\w+)(=((\"[^"]*\")|\S+))?/;'
```

Answer (score 0):

It can get hairy to parse a command line with switches.
Something like below.

```
 # /([^ =]+)(?:=(?|"((?:[^"\\]*(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)*))"|([^ ]*)))?

 / 
 ( [^ =]+ )                    # (1)
 (?:
      = 
      (?|
           "
           (                             # (2 start)
                (?:
                     [^"\\]* 
                     (?:
                          \\ . 
                       |  
                          [^"\\]* 
                     )*
                )
           )                             # (2 end)
           "
        |  
           ( [^ ]* )                     # (2)
      )
 )?
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 15 ) 
/Switch1=Value1  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 7 ) 
Switch1  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 9 , len 6 ) 
Value1  

-------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 16 , len 18 ) 
/Switch2="Value 2"  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 17 , len 7 ) 
Switch2  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 26 , len 7 ) 
Value 2  

-------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 35 , len 8 ) 
/Switch3  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 36 , len 7 ) 
Switch3  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 

-------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 44 , len 31 ) 
/Switch4="C:\Program Files\DIR"  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 45 , len 7 ) 
Switch4  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 54 , len 20 ) 
C:\Program Files\DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the lookback searching "switch." and look ahead for the first slash you will have to trim the values after but you got the values
(?<=Switch.=).+(?=/)